# Морфемный разбор слова "удлиненный"

Tags: морфемный-разбор

Подскажите, почему в слове "удлиненный" - корень "дл", в то же время как у его однокоренных сородичей (длина, длинный) - корень "длин"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никита, мнения у составителей словарей разошлись.

[ДЛИНА](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0)

> Существительное, неодушевлённое, женский род, 1-е склонение (тип
> склонения 1d по классификации А. А. Зализняка).
>
> Корень: -длин-; окончание: -а [Тихонов, 1996].
>
> Корень: -дл-; суффикс: -ин; окончание: -а [Кузнецова, Ефремова, 1986].

Ещё немного неразберихи:

> Родственные для [«длина»](https://wordroot.ru/%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) слова — это лексемы, близкие по смыслу, с
> корнем –*длин–,* принадлежащие к разным частям речи. Длина —
> существительное, корень слова — *длин-.*

---

> Родственные для [«удлиненный»](https://wordroot.ru/%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) слова — это лексемы, близкие по
> смыслу, с корнем *–дл–,* принадлежащие к разным частям речи.
> Удлиненный — прилагательное, корень слова — *дл-.*

Comment: А каково ваше мнение? Или правильнее так: есть ли какое-нибудь правило на этот случай?

Comment: Правила нет. Тихонов, Кузнецова, Ефремова - весьма уважаемые лингвисты, и вот поди ж ты... Они мне равно убедительны, если можно так сказать. А душою я за корень *-длин-*. Другой пример - рифма к длине: "Существительное, неодушевлённое, женский род, 1-е склонение (тип склонения 1a по классификации А. А. Зализняка).

Корень: -глин-; окончание: -а [Тихонов, 1996]".

Comment: В любом случае, спасибо вам большое!

Comment: Вы не ответили на вопрос — почему они считают, что корень "дл". А интересно.

Comment: Откуда ж мне знать?! Разошлись мнения-то.

Comment: Есть "длиться", "длительный". "Н" нет.